# Could you make sauerkraut with spinach?

Tags: fermentation

I'm just wondering if you can ferment spinach in a similar way you can ferment cabbage leaves? Would this have appealing results at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something I've never tried, however, my immediate thought is the comparison of cooked cabbage to cooked spinach.

I imagine nothing more than a jar full of green-black slime.

I'd love to hear what happens if you try, though ;)